# Command waiting for User Input, Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a problem which I cannot seem to solve when I am using the `subprocess` module in Python.

When I execute the command in the cmd prompt, the execution is paused till the user gives an input to the question asked (for example password).
The problem is that the question can vary based on the users setting for the software. The question could be for the username first and then the second question could be the password or the question could be straight away for the password. If I knew the question was always for the password, then I could straight away do a `stndin` and the program will continue. But that is not the case. So here is my question

When I spawn a process using `subprocess.Popen(my_command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, the process is waiting for a user input. How can I get the question that the process is asking so that via Python I can get the user input and communicate it to the process.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method.

```
out, err = process.communicate()
print out  # The question is here

out, err = process.communicate("my answers")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had tried the communicate command. But when I use the communicate command, the console outputs the question before printing it out. And the code never reached the `print out`